# Undo single-file local uncommitted change in egit (e.g. svn revert)

Tags: eclipse, egit

Scenario: I have local uncommitted changes to a source file which I want to undo, and get the source file back in its pristine state. In command-line git I would do "git checkout ", but how do I do this in Egit?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4104149/152061 (**send upvotes there**)

```
Right click on the file -> Replace With -> Index
```

(old versions might say `File in Git Index` rather than `Index`)

or if you want to undo all files that have changed, right click on the project -> Team -> Reset.. -> select the 'hard' radio button -> press the Reset button

Answer (score 8):

One work round is to select the file, right click > replace with > local history...

select the last commit you did on that file. You can then check it looks ok then replace it in your workspace

Then finally do a new commit that is effectively undoing the change you made, if you have to.