# How to update only a particular file from one branch to the other using EGIT in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, branch, diff, egit

I've an updated file Constants.java in branch A. Now I need to switch to branch B. I need only the updated Constants.java file in branch B. How do I achieve this using EGIT in eclipse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse git checkout (aka, revert)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750997/eclipse-git-checkout-aka-revert)

Answer (score 1):

To do this in git, you go about it like this:

1. Checkout branch a: `git checkout A`
2. Checkout **file** from branch b: `git checkout B -- Constants.java`
3. Commit your changes: `git commit`

In EGit, the option to check out a single file is quite hidden: it can be found in the "Replace with -> Commit..." context menu of the file. (source from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4104149/1761499)).