# Removes all modifications made to a file in GIT

Tags: git

I use a Git server to control my code versions and updates. I've made a lot of changes to some files and did not commit anything. But I wanna clear all modifications made to a single file cause it didn't work as I expected. Example:

Files modificated:

```
Person.java
Document.java
Address.java
Phone.java
```

I want to "rollback" modifications made to:

```
Address.java
```

There is any way to do it without copying everything from HEAD revision to my current file?

I'm using Git Bash and Eclipse.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you aren't asking about any bash syntax, built-in commands, or functionality, arguably this is only a git question, not a bash question at all. Removing the tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse git checkout (aka, revert)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750997/eclipse-git-checkout-aka-revert)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your situation right, you should be able to simply `checkout` the file in question:

```
git checkout -- Address.java
```

this will reset the changes only in that file. If you have already staged the file for commit (i.e. used git add) you should reset it first:

```
git reset Address.java
```

Comment: That worked well. But for further information, Eclipse with Egit plugin does not provide a shortcut to do this, so it needed to be done by Git bash.

Comment: According to this response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4104149/328977, Eclipse does provide a shortcut to this.