# EGit Rollback to Previous Commit

Tags: java, eclipse, egit

I want to roll back to a previous project version B in Eclipse when I currently have version A in my workspace because there are some mistakes in A where I simply want to go back to version B with no merging, etc. How, in EGit, do I accomplish this and get the complete version B and nothing leftover from A? Do I do a "Check out"?

Answer (score 0):

If "Version A" only includes local edits that you have not commited yet, then [Eclipse git checkout (aka, revert)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750997/eclipse-git-checkout-aka-revert) shows how to do what you want.

If "Version A" includes one more more commits in your git history and "version B" is specific https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Resetting_your_current_HEAD explains how to do what you want.

Comment: Yes, this worked thanks. In EGit you accomplish it by right-clicking the project ->Team->Reset. Then to overwrite everything you do a 'Hard Reset.'